# vb Count Up From Time (Last Updated: ** Seconds/Minutes Ago)

Tags: vb.net

Okay, I hate just posting a question with no code, but I literally have no idea how to get started other than to user a `Timer`. I have a Visual Basics program which works with an SQL Table. I'd like to have  a label which shows the user how 'old' their display of the table is.

Each time they edit or refresh the table a label is refreshed with a current time stamp. Formatted as 03:19;27.

However, I'd like to show how many seconds or even just minutes the table was last updated.

For example: 'Last updated: 22 Seconds Ago' OR 'Last Updated: Less Than A Minute Ago'.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object provides all of the properties you need to format the message however you want.  The formatting options in it's [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method may also be very helpful to you.  To get a `TimeSpan` object, you can simply subtract one `Date` from another, like this:

```
Dim span As TimeSpan = lastQueryDate - Date.Now
Dim message As String = String.Format("Last Updated: {0} Seconds Ago", span.TotalSeconds)
```

Or, if you want to use a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, you could get the span of time since the stopwatch was started by accessing its [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, which is also a `TimeSpan` object.